# override default authenticator provider in keycloak.x

Tags: java, keycloak, kerberos, keycloak-services, spnego

I need to change the behavior of the default kerberos authenticator (because of the issue declared here: [KEYCLOAK-19865](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/KEYCLOAK-19865)).

I was hopping I could just create a new factory and use the existing ID:

```
public class CustomSpnegoAuthenticatorFactory implements AuthenticatorFactory, DisplayTypeAuthenticatorFactory {
    public static final String PROVIDER_ID = "auth-spnego"; // ID of the default provider SpnegoAuthenticatorFactory
```

And add the following line in my custom provider: *META-INF/services/org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticatorFactory*

```
org.keycloak.authentication.authenticators.browser.CustomSpnegoAuthenticatorFactory
```

But the still the default provider is used. How can I override the default provider in keycloak.x?

EDIT: We have a lot of installations with existing auth-flows and kerberos configurations. What I'm looking for is to override the default provider, without modifying productive configurations / auth-flows.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a custom ID and replace the authenticator in the authentication flow.

Comment: We have a lot of installations with existing auth-flows and kerberos configurations. What I'm looking for is to override the default provider, without modifying productive configurations / auth-flows.